# Can I open a form in layer action?

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I want to open a form (made in QTDesign) in the layer action. It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  Layer actions can call Python so you can do something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import uic
import os

uifile = r"{path to your UI file}\youruifile.ui"
uiinstance = uic.loadUi(uifile)
uiinstance.exec_()
```

[image]

You could even put that in a python file and call it rather then storing the code in the projet.

*In yourcode.py*

```
from PyQt4 import uic
import os

def loadUI():
    uifile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'youruifile.ui')
    uiinstance = uic.loadUi(uifile)
    uiinstance.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible pass a variable value to the form?

Comment: Where I save the yourcode.py ?

Comment: Save yourcode.py anywhere Pyton can find it. This is can be in `.qgis2\python\` or in the folder with the project.  I tend to go with in the folder with the the project.

Comment: It give the message: module object has no attribute loadUi

Comment: how can I pass a value to a form?

Comment: Just pass at as a argument, or use [% FieldName %]

Comment: Just put [% FieldName %] in the end of the action? no aditional code like in php ?val=12 ?

Comment: `yourcode.somemethod([% FieldName %])`.  It's Python code you can pass anything you want into it.